# Translate a calligraphic painting to identify the artist and when it was painted

Tags: translation

Please help translate this painting to identify the artist and when it was painted.

[image: *help*]

Comment: 路轉影峯環林泉溪畔湖山繞翠氣遠大前程午馬？秋之月寫於海外草屋 成森     I am not very sure about it.

Comment: Just something I noticed, this seems like a mixture of simplified and traditional? E.g. 转 (first column, second character) and 遠 (fourth column, first character)

Comment: I am as also not to sure. In the 4th column from the right, I believe it says Da Daquian? Is that possibly the painter?

Comment: The artist's name is 何成森

Comment: Can you possibly l you possibly tell me the year it very was painted? And what does 2000 summer to autumns mean?

Answer (score 1):

not too sure but my guess is: 

`路轉影峯環
林泉溪畔 
湖山繞翠色
遠大前程
千里盡秋之月
寫於海外草屋
成森`